# How to install ear in local web sphere (automatically)

Tags: unix, batch-file, websphere-6.1

I am looking for automatic Ear deployment for WAS6 application. Is there any default scripts provided by WAS6? If Yes, Please provide me script names and please explain me, how to use that. It would be great help for me.

If there is no default scripts available to deploy ear, How to proceed to write script.

Please do needful.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere Application Server provides a scripting tool, `wsadmin`, that may be used for automating the deployment of applications. See this [Info Center document](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_callappinstall.html) for more details.

```
AdminApp.install('/ears/application1.ear', '[-cluster cluster1]')
```

Also, for more general help in writing scripts using `wsadmin`, here are some other helpful resources:

- [WebSphere Application Server V6.1: System Management and Configuration: Administration with Scripting (Chapter 5)](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/SG247304/)
- [WebSphere Application Server V6.1 InfoCenter: Wsadmin tool](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_commandline.html)

Comment: Shelly, Thank u for quick update. I am new to these concepts. As per above link, I understood JACL scripting is required to run above script. Jacl scripting where we can run? Is it in command prompt.

Comment: `wsadmin` is the WAS scripting tool that can be run using either JACL or Jython. JACL is its default language, but Jython is recommended because WAS deprecated its use of JACL.

`wsadmin` can be executed from `<WAS_ROOT>/bin/wsadmin.sh` (or `wsadmin.bat`). For initial testing, you might want to run it interactively (`<WAS_ROOT>/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython`), but you can also write wsadmin script files that contain the Jython/JACL code which can be executed (`<WAS_ROOT>/bin/wsadmin.sh -f yourScriptFile.py`).