# application.xml cannot be read due to XSD

Tags: xsd, ear

I am using maven to build an ear and, after making it with java 1.6, I am trying to deploy on Websphere 6.1. Upon deployment it gives this warning and then the error below:

```
> +++ Warning +++: Sun Feb 12 10:17:03 AST 2012    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4:  Failed to read
> schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd',
> because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be
> read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

error:

```
> org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.
> exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: META-INF/application.xml
> Stack trace of nested exception:
> org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.ResourceLoadException:
> IWAE0007E Could not  load resource "META-INF/application.xml" in
> archive "D:\IBM\SDP70\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\AppSrv
> 01\wstemp\0\upload\finapp-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" Stack trace of nested
> exception: Wrapped exception org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1:
> **Cannot find the declaration of element 'application'.**     at
> org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
> Source)
```

I tried searching on the forum and on Google but couldn't really find anything concrete on it.

I even tried to put the application_6.xsd in the `{WAS_HOME}/runtimes/base_61/properties/schemas/` but to no avail.

The `application.xml` is actually made by maven so I don't think there should be any problem with it. This is what it looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DeploymentDescriptorLoadException` means that the `application.xml` is not valid. The generated code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
```

is incomplete. Use the WebSphere Application Server Toolkit as in these questions:

- [deployment.xml for WebSphere and Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275668/1113772)
- [How to install ear in local web sphere (automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180669/1113772)

**References**

- [Assembling a Web services-enabled client JAR file into an EAR file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_assembclient.html)